# Getting number of lines in a div

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find number of lines in a div like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C8CaX/220/), but instead of returning 5 it is giving me 9. Any idea what is wrong here

```
var lines = document.getElementById('ptest').textContent;  
alert(lines.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/).length);
```

P.S. - I also want to use the code to read the num of lines in a paragraph

Comment: that's because there are 9 lines in that div - an `<li>` is a **list item** not a **line**

Comment: document.getElementById('ptest') returns 9 lines

Comment: If you want to know how many list items you have you could simply use $('ul li').length (jQuery)

Comment: here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C8CaX/221/) that shows you the 9 lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `filter(String)` to remove empty arrays

```
var len=document.getElementById('ptest').textContent.split(/\n/).filter(function(a){ var b = a.replace(/ /g,''); return (typeof(b) == 'string' &&  b != '')}).length

alert(len)
```

Comment: have you had to do this before?  I wonder what a good use-case may be...

Comment: I know about `filter(String)` and just try it on something paragraph.

Comment: @BartekGładys I have tried filter(String) just now, the output is ["  ", "  a", "  a", "  a", "  a", "  a", "  "], still it is having two extra white spaces, any idea about this ?

Comment: @BartekGładys, it works for this case, but if text is dynamically loaded, it takes random number of white spaces depending on formatting of markup as in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C8CaX/223/), Is there anyway to remove all the whitespaces(whether 1 or 2 or more). Your help is most appreciated :)

Comment: @madhur ok now it working, i used also `replace` to temporary delete all spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You may have some extra new line character after 
opening div or before closing div.

```
<div>

asd asda sdf
asd
sdsa sada</div>
```

will give you **5** output.

while

```
<div>asd asda sdf
asd
sdsa sada</div>
```

will give you correct output as 3